# reading index value of a table row with many cells and reading the value from it using Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
//PHP array   
 $Cashups = array(
    array(
        'cashup_id' => 146456,
        'display_time' => 'Wed 16th Mar, 9:55pm',
        'terminal_name' => 'Bar 1',
        'calculated_cash' => 389.20,
        'actual_cash' => 374.6,
        'calculated_tenders_total' => 1,551.01,
        'actual_tenders_total' => 1,551.01
    ),
    array(
        'cashup_id' => 146457,
        'display_time' => 'Wed 16th Mar, 9:56pm',
        'terminal_name' => 'Bar 2',
        'calculated_cash' => 493.3,
        'actual_cash' => 493.3,
        'calculated_other' => 1509.84,
        'actual_other' => 1509.84
    )
);
```

HTML

```
<?php foreach ($Cashups as $Cashup) { ?> 
<tr>
    <td class="Left"><?php echo $Cashup['display_time']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Cashup['terminal_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo number_format($Cashup['calculated_cash'], 2); ?></td>
    <td class="clickchange"><a  href="#"><?php echo number_format($Cashup['actual_cash'], 2); ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo number_format($Cashup['calculated_other'], 2); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo number_format($Cashup['actual_other'], 2); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Jquery

I am able to input text boxes when clicked on the link(clickchange) with the help of an answer sent by user on stackoverflow.
I can read the values but am not able to read the indexes of the links when clicked. I would like to know how to apply each on function to read the indexes of the link. Once I read the inexes I can then update the td with thier respective values.

Please help. How do I read text?

Comment: Where is the jQuery code? You tagged it as jQuery but provided (possibly irrelevant) PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want the index when `clickChange` is clicked.

```
$("td.clickchange").click(function() {
    var i = $(this).parent("tr").index();
    alert(i);
});
```

Comment: This answer could be helpful, if OP would clarify, at what event to read the index, and what are the values he intents to read.

Comment: Perfect answer! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.